# Excel formula to compare two cells for getting lowest value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I need the formla to find lowest price of each category of fruit and SET True for lowest price.
This is the data

```
**Fruits  Price Result**
  APPLE   100    False
  APPLE   125    False
  APPLE   85     True
  ORANGE  40     True
  ORANGE  50     False
  GRAPES  90     False
  GRAPES  70     True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) - This means you need to enter the formula, and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, not just <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If correctly added, you should notice curly braces `{}` around the formula appear.

`=(MIN(IF($A:$A=A2,$B:$B,""))=B2)`

This works by looking through the entire range of column A for values matching your original value on that row. If it exists, the value from column B is included for calculation. It will then find the minimum value of those returned values, and match it against the value on the same row. Hence, you will receive `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether that minimum value matches the one the current row.

[image]